# C# Singleton pattern using Lazy<T>

Tags: c#, .net, singleton, lazy-loading

I was reading this [article](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton) by Jon Skeet.

In one the samples, he talks about using `Lazy<T>` to implement singleton pattern.

This is how the code looks:

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}
```

He does mention at the end

```
  It also allows you to check whether or not the instance has been created yet with the IsValueCreated property, if you need that.
```

`IsValueCreated` indicates whether the lazy object is initialized or not.

I am wondering to ensure this class remains Singleton (only one insteace is created), where and how I would use **IsValueCreated** property ?

Comment: To ensure a singleton, you don't need to worry about the `IsValueCreated`. `Lazy<T>` will do that for you, internally checking the `Value` delegate has been executed and if so, just return the martialized value, not execute the delegate again.

Comment: @PaulG: can you please add sample code for `Value delegate has been executed and if so, just return the martialized value, not execute the delegate again`

Comment: Per your example the delegate is the `Func` that creates the instance of the `Singleton` `() => new Singleton()`.
On the first access of the `Value` property the delegate or `Func` will be executed, materializing the value which will then be remembered. Subsequent accessors of `Value` will get this value, and the delegate or `Func` will not be re-materialized.

Answer (score 4):

`Lazy<T>` ensures that only a single instance is ever created, and that instance will be returned when accessing the `Value` property - however, the creation of such instance is delayed until the first call to `Value`.

That means, for the given code sample you *do not* need to check if the instance has already been initialized - this is what Lazy does for you.

However, you have the ability to check so, which could be useful when dealing with a `T` of `IDisposable` (or anything that implements this interface). In that case, you can check for `IsValueCreated` in the dispose method, before trying to call `Dispose()` on that object (which would in turn uselessly force the creation of the lazy).